# ICEFaces: Press enter on ice:selectInputText also submits values of other ice:selectInputTexts

Tags: jsf, icefaces-1.8

With ICEFaces 1.8.2 I created a page with two ice:selectInputTexts, both using autocompletion functionality. When the user changes the value of the first ice:selectInputText and waits for a second, my bean receives a value change event for the first ice:selectInputText  only.

If the user changes the value in the first ice:selectInputText and presses enter, my bean receives two events: one for each ice:selectInputText.

The problem is that first the event changes the currently selected item and that the second event updates a value of this new item with the value of the previous item!

Is there a way to prevent this second value change event when the user presses enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial submit mechanism, used widely in ICEFaces 1.8, relies on submitting the entire form for accurate lifecycle processing, so this normal behaviour. You can try separating the selectInputText in different forms.